# How to graph the phase response of an Allpass Filter using Desmos?

Tags: calculus, physics, graphing-functions

A single pole allpass filter has the following general phase response:
[Graph of Allpass phase rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dtXj.png).

The equation of an allpass is given here:
[Phase equation of an allpass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhu0h.png).

Allpass filters in general are discussed [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/realsimple/DelayVar/Phasing_First_Order_Allpass_Filters.html).

I am wondering how I can graph the phase response of an allpass filter in desmos.com like given by [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dtXj.png) given a specified fc (cutoff frequency).

Secondly, I am wondering how I can graph the phase response of two allpass filters in series with different specified cutoff frequencies for each.

Any help? What do I need to put in Desmos to get these things to graph?

Thanks.

Comment: So your equation is a function of $\omega$ (lets call it $x$ for the sake of graphing). What is $\omega_b$? Some fixed constant?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h8mmbfiodj

Comment: Thanks Rahul! That's perfect. How would I graph two filters in series? ie.  If I ran a filter at w=200, then wanted to run another filter at w=5000 on the result? Is there an equation you could give me that would allow two such filters in series with different w values? I'd like to be able to expand the equation to up to 10 filters cascading in series. If you can show me how to put two together I would hope I can figure out the rest. Thanks again.

Comment: Is it just simply a matter of adding them together, like this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e9aiem7f4d  ??